# Group rows in dataframe by common elements using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset in which different rows have different combinations of elements, and I want to pull out groups of rows that have the same element combinations. For this example dataset:

```
id <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
X1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,"X1")
X2 <- c(NA,NA,"X2","X2")
X3 <- c("X3","X3","X3","X3")
X4 <- c("X4", "X4", "X4", "X4")
df <- data.frame(id,X1,X2,X3,X4)

> df
   id   X1   X2 X3 X4
   1  A <NA> <NA> X3 X4
   2  B <NA> <NA> X3 X4
   3  C <NA>   X2 X3 X4
   4  D   X1   X2 X3 X4
```

I want to be able pull out

- which ids have X1 & X2 & X3 & X4 (D)
- which ids have !X1 & X2 & X3 & X4 (C)
- which ids have !X1 & !X2 & X3 & X4 (A and B).

I've tried splitting the data frame into lists and removing the empty cells, so that each id gets its own data.frame in the list:

```
df.list <- split(df, seq(nrow(df)))
dfComplete.list <- lapply(df.list, function(remNA) remNA[,colSums(is.na(remNA)) < nrow(remNA)])
```

which leaves me with

```
> dfComplete.list
$`1`
  id X3 X4
1  1 X3 X4

$`2`
  id X3 X4
2  2 X3 X4

$`3`
  id X2 X3 X4
3  3 X2 X3 X4

$`4`
  id X1 X2 X3 X4
4  4 X1 X2 X3 X4
```

I'm stumped as to where to go from here. Is there a way to group the dataframes within the list based on the elements/columns they have in common?

The real dataset I'm working with actually has elements/columns X7 through X17, and each id has somewhere between 1 and 4 elements, so an ideal solution would be able to identify all the combinations of elements present in my data.

And finally, my data were originally in the below long form before I reshaped it to the above noted format, just in case there's an easier way to find a solution from the original format:

```
id <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D")
elements <- c("X3", "X4", "X3", "X4", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")
dataLong <- data.frame(id, elements)

> dataLong
  id elements
1   A       X3
2   A       X4
3   B       X3
4   B       X4
5   C       X2
6   C       X3
7   C       X4
8   D       X1
9   D       X2
10  D       X3
11  D       X4
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

The `reshape2::dcast` function can help to convert data from long-format to the format OP is expecting it to be.

```
#Data
id <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D")
elements <- c("X3", "X4", "X3", "X4", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")
dataLong <- data.frame(id, elements, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(reshape2)

#Use dcast to get the result
dataLong %>% dcast(id~elements)
#   id   X1   X2 X3 X4
# 1  A <NA> <NA> X3 X4
# 2  B <NA> <NA> X3 X4
# 3  C <NA>   X2 X3 X4
# 4  D   X1   X2 X3 X4
```

Comment: I think he is after something else. You may want to review the question again: "ideal solution would be able to identify all the combinations of elements present in my data."

Comment: @dmi3kno May be you are correct. It seems he got data in long format and want to spread it:-)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to count unique combinations. This is how I would go about it

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataLong %>% mutate(value=1) %>% 
  spread(elements, value) %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  summarise(count=n()) %>% ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      X1    X2    X3    X4 count
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1     1     1
#> 2    NA     1     1     1     1
#> 3    NA    NA     1     1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyverse` for this! The use of `arrange()` is a bit superfluous, but I wanted to show you that option since it will arrange your dataframe to reflect the groupings that you are interested in (you can think of this as a kind of nested sort). This may be all you need.

If you want actual counts, as well as a column that tells you which ids correspond to which combinations, then just run the full code below. Note that you will have to add in *all* of your variables (`X7:X17`) in your full code. You'll also want to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when declaring your dataframe, which is good practice in general.

```
# Your example dataframe. Make sure to set stringsAsFactors = FALSE
id <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
X1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,"X1")
X2 <- c(NA,NA,"X2","X2")
X3 <- c("X3","X3","X3","X3")
X4 <- c("X4", "X4", "X4", "X4")
df <- data.frame(id,X1,X2,X3,X4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# We group rows by all unique combinations and then collapse those rows, 
# while recording which ids belong to which grouping, and how many there are 
# in each.
library(tidyverse)
ndf <- arrange(df, X1,X2,X3,X4) %>%
       group_by(X1,X2,X3,X4) %>%
       summarise(num = n(), id = paste(id, collapse=","))

# Output:
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   X1, X2, X3 [?]
  X1    X2    X3    X4      num id   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>
1 X1    X2    X3    X4        1 D    
2 <NA>  X2    X3    X4        1 C    
3 <NA>  <NA>  X3    X4        2 A,B
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help!